# Problem with cordova emulate android and Gradle

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I'm new in android apps development. I created a new ionic project. When I try in the console cordova emualte android it fails with this errors:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0/gradle-2.3.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0/gradle-2.3.0.pom'.
               > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.4.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 7s
```

I try curl https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0/gradle-2.3.0.pom in the console and worked.
Thanks for any help!!

Comment: open this project in android studio and try to sync with Gradle

Comment: 2.3.0 was released in 2017.....You said you're new to mobile development, so why not start using Ionic 5 and Cordova 9.1.0 which requires newer 4.0+ gradle plugin that is more compatible?